# How many kinds of asynchronous mechanism are there in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous

In what situation, Android system will enter the asynchronous mode? (here "asynchronous mode" I mean do something in the future)

As far as I know, there's at least 5:

1. bindService -> ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected
2. sendBroadcast -> Receiver.onReceive
3. sendMessage/post -> handleMessage
4. Thread.start -> Runnable.run
5. AsyncTask.execute -> doInBackground

But I'm not sure are these all situations? Are there any more?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by asynchronous mode-  you aren't clear.  If you mean ways to do something in the future, lots.  If you mean to do something on another thread half of your current list is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation, actually I mean do something in the future. So can you list others?

Comment: Hi! I am not 100% sure but I think AsyncTask uses Thread. But my question is why do you need that list ? :-)

Comment: Since asynchronization means a different kind of control flow change, given a component in Android apk file, I want to find a closure of that component using static control flow analysis. So I need to know all kinds of the ways.